# A sobolev inequality in real analysis. To bound a function by the intergral of its derivative and itself.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that for every postive number $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a constant $C_\varepsilon>0$, such that the inequality
$$
\underset{x\in[a,b]}{\sup}|f^2(x)|\le C_\varepsilon\int_a^b f^2(x)dx+\varepsilon\int_a^b\left(f'(x)\right)^2dx
$$
holds for every $f\in C^1\left([a,b]\right)$. I happened to know this is a kind of so-called "Sobolev" inequality, but I still can not prove it. Please help me!

Now I have proved the proposition if the left side  is replaced with
$$
\underset{x\in[a,b]}{\sup}|f^2(x)-f^2(a)|
$$
using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must exist an $x_0\in [a,b]$ such that
\begin{align}
|f(x_0)|^2\leq \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b|f(t)|^2\,dt,
\end{align}
because otherwise we could integrate both sides of the reversed inequality to get a contradiction. Now, use the FTC with the starting point $x_0$ instead of $a$ (as you seem to have done). Then, for all $x\in [a,b]$,
\begin{align}
f(x)^2=[f(x)^2-f(x_0)^2]+f(x_0)^2\leq \dots
\end{align}
Cauchy-Schwarz as you have done, and the inequality above will complete the proof.

Comment: So C_ε depends not only on ε, but also on the length of the interval?

Comment: @SlInevitable2003 yes, it must. Consider $f=1$. If $C_{\epsilon}$ didn't depend on the length of the interval, try to show you'll get a contradiction.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!